# Cannot set array values into select2

Tags: javascript, java, jquery-select2

On my edit jsp page I have a select2 dropdown and when edit jsp page is loaded I want to set all values of array as selection in select2 dropdown. I have following function of javascript written on jsp page

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function initSelect2(selectIds) {

           //here it initializes all select ids by iterating

          $("#" + iterated select id).attr("multiple","multiple");

          $("#" + iterated select id).select2();
 }</script>
```

Then in $(document).ready function I have written below mentioned code that iterates through map keys and the sets the value of iterated key in select2 element. **selectValuesForAttMap** is hashmap.Its type and values are

```
Map<String,List<String> selectValuesForAttMap = new Map<String,List<String>();
```

and it will have entries for example

1-selVal-3,[category:category@ku@CATEGORY, category:pages@ku@CATEGORY] 
1-selVal-5,[grams:1@ku@GRAMS]   where 1-selVal-3 is the key and [category:category@ku@CATEGORY, category:pages@ku@CATEGORY]  is the value and so on for other entries.Here 1-selVal-3 is the id of select tag and category:category@ku@CATEGORY  is the value to be set

```
       var multiSelAttrVal = "",entryKey ="";

        <%
            System.out.println("--------------Map values--------------------------");

            Iterator it = selectValuesForAttMap.entrySet().iterator();
            //iterating through map values 
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                 System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
        %>
                multiSelAttrVal = "<%=pair.getValue()%>";
                entryKey = "<%=pair.getKey()%>";

                console.log("Key =" +entryKey + "Value=" + multiSelAttrVal);
                //splitting values by comma
                var splitValues = multiSelAttrVal.split(",");
                var strToBeSet = "";

                var array1 = [];
                //set the splitted values in array
                if(splitValues.length > 0) {
                     for(var i=0; i< splitValues.length;i++) {
                         strToBeSet += splitValues[i]
                         array1[i] = splitValues[i].trim().replace("]","");
                         array1[i] = array1[i].trim().replace("[","");
                    } 
                } 

                console.log("array=" + array1);
                console.log("strToBeSet=" + strToBeSet);

               //set multiple values in select element
                $("#"+entryKey.trim()).val(array1);

                <% it.remove();  %>

        <%  } %>
```

I am trying to set the values using below line but value is not getting set.Can someone help me to find out the issue?

> $("#"+entryKey.trim()).val(array1);

Comment: Well, does array1 contain an array of existing <option> values?  Does entryKey contain the id of your select element?  Should work if so.  Maybe post the result of your console.log.

Comment: Yes , it contains.I have checked using console.log

Comment: Without seeing what the various variables contain it's hard to guess what could be going wrong.  I would think something like `$("#<%=pair.getKey()%>").val(JSON.parse("<%=pair.getValue()%>"));` would work, saving a bunch of typing.

Comment: Values from console                                                                                               Key =1-selVal-3 Value=[category:category@ku@CATEGORY, category:pages@ku@CATEGORY]                                                                             
array=category:category@ku@CATEGORY,category:pages@ku@CATEGORY                                                                                                              
strToBeSet=[category:category@ku@CATEGORY category:pages@ku@CATEGORY]